# Array of chars to a single integer

Tags: c++, parsing

I need a little guidance on converting a char to a single integer value. I am not supposed to use any libraries functions that convert them. I understand how I to convert a single char to an int inside the array using char - '0' = int, my question is if there is a way to take the array of integers and make it one single integer. I am using iostream, string, and cctype.

Thank you

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001591/treating-a-character-array-as-an-integer-learn-c-the-hard-way-extra-credit.

Comment: You *do* know simple arithmetic, and how the decimal system works (multiples of ten and all that)?

Comment: So you have an array of chars like {'1','6', '2'} or an array of integers like {1,6,2}?

Comment: or you want mix all integers and make a big integer number?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    char str[20] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '\0'};  // char string;
    int i, len;

    long long number = 0;                                 // number which stores the value 

    len = strlen(str);                                    // calculate the length of string
    i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        number = 10*number + (str[i] - '0');
    }

    std::cout << number << std::endl;                     // number
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** It can handle all the **+ive** values ranging from **0 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807**. We can even extend it for the **-ive** values, all we have to check whether the first character of the character string is **minus sign (-)** or not.

Comment: If you're going to make claims about the maximum value, please use `int64_t` or `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense I was trying to figure out a way to use 10 somehow. I feel like an idiot for not seeing this in the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, I am running an if statement that says if the first element is negative it subtracts else it adds.

Comment: @Motorscooter Now, do you have any doubt? comments Most welcome.

Comment: @psyco It all seems clear the rest should be pretty simple to figure out. Thank you again.